# Web Scraping with VBA with data binding

Tags: html, excel, vba, msxml

I'm totally new to VBA. To kickstart my journey I started watching tutorial series from WiseOwlTutorials. From the video part 46 and 47, I'm taught on how to use query table to extract the data. After which we moved on to MSXML. I tried the example provided and decided to move on by finding a website that I'm interested in.

Below shows the code and inspect element of the website.

[image]

Soon I realize the data is not in the form of table, and I could not use the method taught in the video. `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementsById` to obtain the data. I tried to google for data binding, name and value but I could not find the way using VBA.

I'm trying to find out how do I do it with MSXML, if it is not possible what other tools do I need? Thank you.

```
Sub GetSGXMatrics()
    Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    XMLPage.Open "GET", "http://www.sgx.com/wps/portal/sgxweb/home/company_disclosure/stockfacts?page=2&code=Q01&lang=en-us", False
    XMLPage.send

    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText
    GeneralRetrieve HTMLDoc
End Sub


Sub GeneralRetrieve(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)
    Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Set HTMLTables = HTMLPage.getElementsByTagName("table")

    For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables
        For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.Children
            Debug.Print vbTab & HTMLRow.innerText
        Next HTMLRow
    Next HTMLTable
End Sub
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5if0.jpg
This is the source image. I do not know why its not shown in my post.

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @nishitdey Hi, there wasn't an error message. When I try run this module, I couldnt get data-name or data-value. I do not know what I did wrongly. However, I realize at the source it says, showhidden: is data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data you want is returned by xhr (check it is present in page source view of website)......

You need to loop the td (table cells) within table rows, then test whether current td has either the data-name and/or data-value attributes; where present the extract with getAttribute method of node

```
Dim td As MSHTML.HTMLTableCell

For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.Rows
    For Each td In HTMLRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
        If td.hasAttribute("data-name") Then Debug.Print td.getAttribute("data-name")
        If td.hasAttribute("data-name") Then Debug.Print td.getAttribute("data-name")
    Next
Next HTMLRow
```